# Comparison of two lists in java using for loop

Tags: java, list

I have two list `word` containing words (word is a copy of the list words) and `existingGuesses` containing characters and I want to compare them (means compare whether each character is present in the list `word` or not) by iterating through a for loop. Can anybody suggest me how to do the comparison?

```
  public List<String> getWordOptions(List<String> existingGuesses, String newGuess)            
   {
     List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>(words);

 /* String  c = existingGuesses.get(0);
    ListIterator<String> iterator = word.listIterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){

     if(word.contains(c)) 
     {
         word.remove(c);
     }
    }*/
    for(String temp: word){
        for(String cha: existingGuesses){

    }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you post some example input and expected output?

Comment: you say existingGuesses contains character while here you have declared as containing string?

Comment: by the way it is a bad practice to name `List<String>` as **word** (whereas it looks like **words**). If there is a list of one-character strings name it so: characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the guesses in words like this by using the [List#contains(Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
for(String myGuess: existingGuesses){
    if(word.contains(myGuess)) {
        // Do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following O(N) complexity code

```
public List<String> getWordOptions(List<String> existingGuesses, String newGuess) {
    List<String> word = new ArrayList<String>(words);
    for (String cha : existingGuesses) {

        if (word.contains(cha)) {
            word.remove(cha);
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare them and remove them if its there,

Then You can use the [`List#removeAll(anotherlist)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

(Got clue from   `word.remove(c);`) from your commented code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Collection.retainAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
List<String> word=new ArrayList<String>();//fill list
List<String> existingGuesses=new ArrayList<String>();//fill list

List<String> existingWords=new ArrayList<String>(word);

existingWords.retainAll(existingGuesses);

//existingWords will only contain the words present in both the lists
System.out.println(existingWords);
```